# Storing a string into a vector

Tags: c++, string, sorting, vector, stl

The error says that no matching function to call for `push_back()`.

I included `<vector>` so I don't understand why this error is occurring. If you could also show me how to take in a string and store it into a vector that would be really helpful!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> list;
    char input;
    while(cin>>input)
    {
        list.push_back(input);
    }
    for(int i=0;list.size();i--)
    {
        cout<<list[99-i];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

Since your `list` is a `vector` of `string`, pushing single `char`s into it wouldn't work: you should either make it a vector of `char`s, or read `string`s:

```
string input;
while(cin>>input) {
    list.push_back(input);
}
```

Note that `list[99-i]` is rather suspicious: it will work only if the `list` has exactly `99` elements, and only if you change `i--` for `i++`. Otherwise, you would get undefined behavior either on accessing elements past the end of the vector, or accessing elements at negative indexes.

If you would like to print the list from the back, use `list[list.size()-1-i]` instead, and use `i++` instead of `i--`, because otherwise the loop would not stop.

Comment: I fixed my code but I'm still getting some errors:

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> list;
    string input;
    
    
    while(cin>>input&& input!='\n')
    {
        list.push_back(input);
    }
    
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i--)
    {
        cout<<list[list.size()-1-i];
    }
    
    cout<<"verifying that the string:"<<input<<" was in the string"<<endl;
    
}

Comment: @Darraptor the comparison with `"\n"` should be removed ([demo](http://ideone.com/ntN9YX)). It's of no use anyway, because operator `>>` treats `'\n'` as a delimiter, so it wouldn't put it into a string. If you want to check for an empty line, use this condition: `in>>input&& input.size() != 0`

Answer (score 2):

Well, the error is correct. It helps, though, to read *all* of it!

The class `vector<string>` has a function `push_back(const string&)`.

It does not have a function `push_back(char)`.

I don't know why you're extracting individual `char`s but storing whole `string`s; don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to put in char into a string vector.
Change input to string.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
int n;
cin>>n;
string v;
vector<string> s;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin>>v;
    s.push_back(v);
   
}

sort(s.begin(),s.end());
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cout<<s[i]<<endl;;
   
}
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Recommending the use of `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` in an answer on Stack Overflow is just asking for downvotes. See: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/10871073) Another good read: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/10871073)